# Use output of cat or grep as input into sed

Tags: text-processing

I've looked at similar posts on this site, but have not been able to make them work for my problem.

I have an input file (ids.txt) that holds 8 digit ID numbers, 1 per line. Something like this:

```
11111111
22222222
```

Then I have a CSV file (users.csv) like this:

```
username_prefix user_type   expiry_date comments
11111111    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
22222222    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
33333333    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
44444444    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
55555555    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
```

I want to use the IDs file as input to a sed command (or something) so that any lines in the CSV file that match the username_prefix field to an ID get moved to a new file.
So the expected output of this process would be that the original CSV file would look like this:

```
username_prefix user_type   expiry_date comments
33333333    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
44444444    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
55555555    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
```

And there will be a new CSV file that contains the removed lines, like:

```
username_prefix user_type   expiry_date comments
11111111    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
22222222    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
```

I tried the following command, but it generated a 0 byte output file.

```
cat ids.txt | sed "/$/d" ./adhocUsers_upload_EDT0029448.csv > removed.csv
```

BTW, solution doesn't have to use `sed`. It just seemed to be the appropriate tool from what I googled.

Comment: IMHO it would be far simpler to use `awk` e.g. something like `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++; next} FNR==1 || ($1 in a) {print > "removed.csv"} FNR==1 || !($1 in a) {print}' idfile input.csv`

Comment: Instead of AWK it might be possible to save the output into a variable and then use the variable

Comment: Are the files CSV or whitespace-separated?

Comment: The ID file is just a text file with 1 ID per line. The users file is a CSV. The commas didn't come across when I copied the above sample from Excel.

Comment: Two invocations of the `join` command (one to get the matches and one to get the misses) would be enough, with the following caveats: 1) the header line would have to be stripped before processing and added back afterwards and 2) the files have to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a ruby solution. It's a "bit" longer, but it also works when the IDs are in an order that is different from the users file. (And it's a bit more maintanable than sed)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ids = []
users = {}
header = ""
# Read the contents of the user-file into a Hash
File.open('users.csv','r') do |users_file|
    header = users_file.gets
    users_file.each do |line|
        id, *content = line.chomp.split(',')
        users[id] = content
    end
end
# For each line in the id-file, add an appropriate line to the removed-file.
File.open('ids.txt','r') do |ids_file|
    File.open('removed.csv', 'a') do |removed_file|
        removed_file.puts header
        ids_file.each do |line|
            id = line.chomp
            if users[id]
                removed_file.puts "#{id},#{users[id].join(',')}"
                users.delete id
            end
        end
    end
end
# Finally fill the original file with what's left
File.open('original.csv', 'a') do |original_file|
    original_file.puts header
    users.each_pair do |id, line|
        original_file.puts "#{id},#{line.join(',')}"
    end
end
```

Your output will be in the files "original.csv" and "removed.csv". If this isn't where you envisioned it to be, just move the files around ;)

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. I thought I could be cleaver and do this as some one line SED command, but it's all gone pear shaped. I was actually half way through writing a python script instead, but you beat me with your ruby script. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Oh, I also updated your post to include the commas I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sound it's pretty easy for `awk` command:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{IDs[$0]++;next} 
            { print >(($1 in IDs)?"removed.csv":"Updated.csv")}
' IDs.txt Users.csv
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it's failing to match anything. The "out.csv" file is exactly the same size as CSV.csv, and no "removed.csv" is being generated. I don't know enough about `awk` to know how to debug this.

Comment: @AFSHIN: The OP says that the `.csv` file is — wait for it — really a CSV file, and it is just shown wrong in the question. You need to add ```-F,```.

Comment: Nice one. With that update, this code is now doing exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this script, it will save matched lines in `removed.csv` and everything else will be send to stdout. Note that the `username_prefix user_type   expiry_date comments` line will not be send to `removed.csv` file, so you must add it manually.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

id_file=${1}
csv_file=${2}
removed_file=${3}

while read -r user; do

  matched=''

  while read -r id; do
      if <<< "${user}" grep -F -e "${id}" > '/dev/null'; then
        matched='yes'
        break
      else
        matched='no'
      fi
  done < "${id_file}"

  [[ "${matched}" == 'yes' ]] && echo "${user}" >> "${removed_file}"
  [[ "${matched}" == 'no' ]] && echo "${user}"

done < "${csv_file}"
```

Example:

```
$ myscript.sh ids.txt users.csv removed.csv
username_prefix user_type   expiry_date comments
33333333    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
44444444    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
55555555    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
$ cat removed.csv
11111111    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
22222222    SomeTypeHere    31/12/2017  EDT0029448
```